# What are these called

Tags: types, window, modal-dialog

I am interested in creating a window that displays over the website, and grays out the background when a form is processing a credit card transaction. The window will include a spinner and I want to make sure the spinner does not lock when the processing is taking place. What are these windows called and where would you suggest I obtain information on how to develop this?

Answer (score 0):

Modal popup? Standby popup?

The Ajax control in asp.net to do this is called an UpdateProgress. I think that's a lousy name, though.

Comment: Don't modal popups require user interaction though?

Comment: Not by definition - I would say that a window is modal by the fact that it prevents the user from interacting with what is behind it. It MAY require the user to take some action, or it may simply go away on its own.

Comment: So, using asp.net, the updateprogress will accomodate what I am trying to accomplish? If so, is there still a better way to do it?

Comment: I'm a big fan of JQuery IU (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), which has a modal dialog. It has a lot of other fun stuff, too, so set aside some time to look at it :).